# Why doesn't my code always detect palindromes in substrings correctly?

Tags: c#, algorithm, substring

I am working with an algorithm that should find longest palindrome within a given string. So far, I've done some R & D and got a solution that's almost similar to mine. After doing some tweaks, got the following so far:

```
public static string Find_LongestPalindrome(string s)
{
    var charsArray = s.ToCharArray();
    var boolArr = new bool[charsArray.Length, charsArray.Length];
    
    int longestStart = 0;
    int maxLength = 1;
    
    //By default, the matching array indexes are kept true for tracking similar characters
    for (int i = 0; i < charsArray.Length; i++)
    {
        boolArr[i, i] = true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < charsArray.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        //This checks if there are matching characters and their length in the given string
        if (charsArray[i] == charsArray[i + 1])
        {
            boolArr[i, i + 1] = true;
            longestStart = i;
            maxLength = 2;
        }
    }

    //Keeps track of the character length that has length of two in a substring
    for (int length = 2; length <= charsArray.Length; length++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < charsArray.Length - length + 1; i++)
        {
            int j = i + length - 1;
            if (charsArray[i] == charsArray[j] && boolArr[i + 1, j - 1])
            {
                boolArr[i, j] = true;
                if (maxLength < (j - i))
                {
                    maxLength = j - i;
                    longestStart = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Returns the substring that's found
    if (s.Length == longestStart + (maxLength + 1))
    {
        return s.Substring(longestStart, maxLength + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return s = "none";
    }
}
```

Here's the fiddle that I did so far: [Longest Palindrome](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O8X6TC)

The above solution worked, but unable to get the desired solution for one of the following input:

(The logic here is to find the longest palindrome in a given string that has at least length of two and greater)

**Input 1**: `hellosmithsannas` **Output 1**: `sannas` 
**Input 2**: `hellosannasmith` **Output 2**: `sannas` 
**Input 3**: `abcdefgg` **Output 3**: `none`

In my case, the code I tried is able to run for the inputs 1 and 3. But for the input 2, I am getting `none`, though it should return `sannas` as the minimum length is two and the longest string is found in a pattern. Is there anything that I missed here?

Comment: I guess that's a case for Visual Studio's step debugger. With your second input, **single-step** though your code and observe how each of the code lines behave and how the content of variables and arrays change in what manner. For every step/code line, verify if the observed behavior aligns with the expected/intended behavior. Doing single-stepping in the debugger should give you ample of insights regarding how/why the unexpected/unintended behavior happened and what you therefore should change in your code...

Comment: "The above solution worked, but unable to get the desired solution" Does the code work or not? Sounds like a contradiction.

Comment: `The above solution worked, but unable to get the desired solution for one of the following input`. Pretty straight-forward @MrSmith42, isn't it?

Comment: @AT-2017 It's actually not clear at all. Reading your entire question, it sounds like your code _doesn't_ work for one of the desired input parameters. So your solution works _partially_ or _sometimes_. But to say it just "worked" is inaccurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (s.Length == longestStart + (maxLength + 1))
```

implies that you're only interested in longest palindromes which happen at the end of the string. To consider palindromes in other locations, it should be just:

```
if (maxLength > 1)
```